# Porto theme - Product page

Tags: configurable-product, theme

My product page is in 3 colums.

How do I put all my swatches in both colum 1 and 2?

I think I need to close a DIV in view.html.

But when I close DIV in view.html - my 3. colum goes down below all.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4ihx.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to put them in both the columns that are column-1 & 2?

Comment: With 65 swatches there will be a long way from main image to "Add to basket" button. The clients have to scroll for seeing image and then scroll for putting in basket.